# Authorize query Transactions

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am integrating with Authorize NET I have implemented Charge Refund and Automated Recurring Payments

But because recurring payments execute on the Authorize server I need to sync them back. Is there a way to get transaction list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a list of transactions you can use the [Transaction Details API](http://developer.authorize.net/api/transaction_details/).

Comment: one more problem, I cannot query the list of transactions triggered by ARB. Is there such an option?